# Output ListBox as multiple line log

Tags: vba

I have run into an issue when automating some of the error checking processes on a database. I need to output a log that is identical to an output to a ListBox, however my current (FreeFile) method, will overwrite the log file each time a new line is added to the box.

```
Sub ExampleString (s As String)
Dim n as Object

n = FreeFile()
Open "C:\Path\TEST.txt" For Output As #n

If Not listBoxOut Is Nothing Then
With listBoxOut
' add items to List Box
Print #n, s
' iterate through List Box
Close #n
End With
End If

End Sub
```

How would I go about ouputting this text in an identical manner to how it is done in the ListBox, over multiple lines?

Thanks,

Neuw

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Dealing with the printing file statements only, you have to:

- change n type to `integer`
- use `Append` keyword

here's the revised code

```
Sub ExampleString(s As String)
    Dim n As Integer

    n = FreeFile()
    Open "C:\Path\TEST.txt" For Append As #n

    If Not listBoxOut Is Nothing Then
        With listBoxOut
            ' add items to List Box
            Print #n, s
            ' iterate through List Box
            Close #n
        End With
    End If
End Sub
```